# Can I login to a linux machine from my script, run a command and get the output?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am new to Protractor/Jasmine/Javascript. I want to write a test case using Protractor, where I want to ssh to a linux machine, run a command there and get the output. Later I want to validate the command output with some data.

Comment: you want to ssh with Javascript O.o.

More seriously, You can setup a list of test and call them with the cmd. Just as we do with grunt/karma. And if you parameter your cmd stdout to a file, you can just recover the result of your test.

The question is : what did you try so far? Are you looking for jasmine documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Use [paramikojs](https://github.com/mimecuvalo/paramikojs) for example.

You can check this code to see how the library is used:

- https://github.com/mimecuvalo/fireftp/blob/master/src/content/js/connection/ssh2.js

But keep in mind that it will not work on normal regular web pages.
There is no way to connect to a plain old SSH server.

You can use WebSockets, but it is not simple TCP sockets.

There are some TCP-WebSockets gates, that you can use in this case. For example:

- https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/tree/master/utils/